# Rendering massive amount of data

Tags: qt, opengl, visualization, data-visualization, bigdata

I have a 3D floating-point matrix, in worst-case scenario the size could be (200000x1000000x100), I want to visualize this matrix using Qt/OpenGL.

Since the number of elements is extremely high, I want to render them in a way that when the camera is far away from the matrix, I just show a number of interesting points that gives an approximation of how the matrix look like. When the camera gets closer, I want to get more details and hence more elements are calculated.

I would like to know if there are techniques that deals with this kind of visualization.

Comment: 1e5³ floating point elements. This amounts to about 4PB of data. Are you sure that figure is correct?

Comment: @datenwolf: i guess his matrix is sparse

Comment: @eznme: Probably. But I'm thinking the worst case scenario. I think the best line of attack would be turning the matrix (assuming it is sparse) into a spatial subdivision tree (Kd or Octree) and visualize that up to a certain forking depth threshold.

Comment: @datenwolf exactly what i would do too

Comment: The computation is related to measurements done on an application executed on a super computer with tens of thousand of nodes, so yes, the numbers are huge. The sparsity of the matrix is dependent on the behavior of behavior of the program.

Comment: Just a hint: besides the great tips given, you might want to search for work on "out-of-core rendering" for some additional material.

Comment: I will check what you suggested/recommended, thanks all

Comment: @datenwolf, I just discovered that I wrote the wrong lengths of each dimension, but it is still very high I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general idea is called **level-of-detail** rendering and is a whole science in itself.

For your domain i would recommend two steps:

1) Reduce the number of cells by averaging (arithmetic-mean function) them in cubes of *different* sizes and caching those cubes (on disk as well as RAM). "Different" means here, that you have the same data in multiple sizes of cubes, e.g. coarse-grained cubes of 10000x10000x10000 and finer cubes of 100x100x100 cells resulting in multiple levels-of-detail. You have to organize these in a hierarchical structure (the larger ones containing multiple smaller ones) and for this i would recommend an **Octree**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

2) The second step is to actually render parts of this Octree:
To do this use the distance of your camera-point to the sub-cubes. Go through the cubes and decide to either enter the sub-cube or render the larger cube by using this distance-function and heuristically chosen or guessed threshold-values.

(2) can be further optimized but this is optional: To optimize this rendering organize the to-be-rendered cube's into layers: The direction of the layers (whether it is in x, y, or z-slices) depends on your camera-viewpoint to which it should be near-perpendicular. Then render each slice into a texture and voila you only have to render a single quad with that texture for each slice, 1000 quads are no problem to render.

Comment: Thanks for the great comment sir, I will research what you mentioned in the next few weeks. I think it would be the best if you could also recommend me with some literature, because I have a different knowledge background, and I need to read more about this topic.

Comment: There is not much you have to read about this, the operations (group recursively in an Octree, average over all data in the cubes and store it, calculate distance to (sub-)cubes, render them) are conceptually easy; but there is an implementation detail that can be tricky and that you have to keep in mind: averaging over many numbers can be numerically unstable; adding all the cells into a single double-precision floating-point number and then dividing it by the number of cells is not optimal (see numeric literature on arithmetic mean).

Answer (score 2):

Qt has some way of rendering huge number of elements efficiently. Check the [examples/demo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/demos-chip.html) that is part of QT.